# Testing HmacSHA256 signature

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, sha

I'm testing my Hmac with test vectors from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231

But on test case 3 "Test with a combined length of key and data that is larger than 64 bytes (= block-size of SHA-224 and SHA-256)." I get a different digest than the correct one.

```
byte[] key = hexify("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
byte[] data = hexify("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
byte[] correct = hexify("773ea91e36800e46854db8ebd09181a72959098b3ef8c122d9635514ced565fe");

// Create digest
SecretKey macKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256");
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(macKey);
byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data);
```

Any idea why they become different? What did I miss? I'm very new to this.

```
// Hex encoded
a5418172bb54bf71f3ec28d1c9f34c48da17007eac4d0ca9e2f8ab54b91603e8
773ea91e36800e46854db8ebd09181a72959098b3ef8c122d9635514ced565fe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue. For me, the following SSCCE works just fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  byte[] key = hexify("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
  byte[] data = hexify("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
  byte[] correct = hexify("773ea91e36800e46854db8ebd09181a72959098b3ef8c122d9635514ced565fe");

  // Create digest
  SecretKey macKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256");
  Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
  mac.init(macKey);
  byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data);
  System.out.println(Arrays.equals(correct, digest));    
}

private static byte[] hexify(String string) {
  return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(string);
}
```

Prints: `true`

Perhaps an error in your display or comparison code?

Comment: Thanks! That code does indeed work :) I didn't post my actual code, since the question code was put together from a Junit test and my implementation code. And I found why it didn't work! The error is from a conversion between String and byte arrays when I'm creating my key.

Comment: @heffaklump This is why we always recommend questions are posted with an SSCCE. Then there is no doubt about the reproducibility of the issue. Glad you've got a fix.

Comment: I believe Arrays.equals is vulnerable to timing attacks, see https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/